# lwjgl double-click mouse events

Tags: java, lwjgl

I'm currently teaching myself LWJGL's mouse class, but there is something I still don't know how to do.  I want to be able to handle double-click mouse events, but I don't know how.

Answer (score 1):

It is not (AFAIK) natively supported. You have to do it yourself.

One way to do that : memorize the event date (System.curentTimeMS() or equivalent).
If the previous clic event was recent (~200 ms), it's a double-clic. else, simple clic.

Hope it helps...